# Spark: Reducing RDD partitions after union

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Despite using `coalesce(2000)`, the following code returns an RDD with 22000 partitions.

```
private [sparse]  def internalEvenProportionPerTargetMultivariate1( labelRdd: RDD[(Double, Int)]): RDDLabeledPoint =
{

    val reducedpartsRDDList: Array[RDD[(LabeledPoint, Int, String)]] = preduceParts(proportionForReductionByLabel,labelRdd)
    val newRDD=reducedpartsRDDList.tail.foldLeft(reducedpartsRDDList.head){ (rdd1, rdd2) 
         => rdd1.union(rdd2) }.coalesce(2000)
    new RDDLabeledPoint(newRDD)
}
```

Originally, there was one RDD with about 500 partitions. This was then broken into 44 subsets in the method `preduceParts` and some rows were removed from each subset.

It seems that `reducedpartsRDDList: Array[RDD[(LabeledPoint, Int, String)]]` is an array of 44 RDDs, each with 500 partitions and that the `union` does not reduce this number, even after `coalesce`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you looking at the number of partitions? For instance, `x.coalesce(n).getNumPartitions` should always be `n`

Comment: And side-note: the `.tail.foldLeft(...){...}` business can just be `.reduce(_.union(_))`

Comment: @Joe K. I am seeing the Spark console output grinding through 22K partitions one the RDD. However, I am beginning to suspect that I am missing some obvious logic error elsewhere. I will revisit and update the question if needed. Thanks